# How to enable Magento 2 Canonical meta tag?

Tags: magento2

I am new Magento Developer. I am finding out for enabling *Magento 2 Canonical Meta Tag* solutions in the most saving time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Better you can refer at >>> http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-canonical-meta-tag/

*Admin panel >>> Store >>> Configuration >>> Catalog —> Catalog —>  Search Engine Optimization *

In Search Engine Optimization:

You can decide to enable Magento 2 Canonical Meta tag for your category or products.

- For only category: Choose Canonical Link Meta Tag for Categories field, select Yes. Like this:

After all, *“Save config”*

You ‘ve already set up your site for support to Search Engine index your site. Besides, please view more at our tutorial post on Venustheme. If you have any question about our post, please feel free to leave your comment here. We are pleased to get your comment and try our best to give you the best tutorials.